# Teradata/SQL sum together columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query that returns two amounts.  I would like to sum them together, while leaving one as it is returned by the query.

For example:

```
DESC | sum(AMOUNT)
A | -61149025.940000
B | -9696.910000
```

B needs to be the sum of B and A and replace the current value.  A stays as is on the result of the query.

My SQL is similar to this:

```
Select SQ.DESC, SUM(SQ.AMOUNT)
FROM (subquery) SQ
GROUP by SQ.DESC
```

My return results would be

```
DESC | sum(AMOUNT)
A | -61149025.940000
B | -61158722.850000
```

I have not been able to logically make sense of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "B" to be the total of all the values, you can use window functions:

```
Select SQ.DESC,
       (CASE WHEN SQ.DESC = 'A' THEN SUM(SQ.AMOUNT)
             WHEN SQ.DESC = 'B' THEN SUM(SUM(SQ.AMOUNT)) OVER ()
        END) as SUM_AMOUNT
FROM (subquery) SQ
GROUP by SQ.DESC
```

Note:  Even if Teradata allows `DESC` as a column name, it is a poor choice because `DESC` is a SQL keyword (think `ORDER BY`).

Comment: Thanks.  My real column name isn't DESC.  You are correct that is is a SQL keyword.